# Return a variadic template of tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I would like to create a `std::tuple` from elements in a `std::vector` and return it from my function. The size of a `std::vector` will not always be three so I need a function that can create a `std::tuple` from three, four and more elements and return it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> create_tuple(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    if (vec.size() == 2)
        return std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1]);
    else if (vec.size() == 3)
        return std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{ 0, 1, 2 };
    auto t = create_tuple(vec);
}
```

Currently there is a compilation error, so how can I fix it? I am using C++11 and I cannot use '`auto`' as a value type returned from the function.

Comment: Why do you want a tuple of all same types? That's what `std::vector` or `std::array` is for.

Comment: You've just completely misunderstood templates and forgot about the statically typed paradigm of C++.

Comment: why do you think you need this? Maybe it is possible to do (anything is after all), but once you have it you would realize that you ended up with exactly same what `std::vector` already offers. Smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: 1/ you can't make this work as stated, because the return type of `create_tuple` is un-knowable at compile time. 2/ If you get an error, you should generally include it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to create a tuple from elements in vector and return it from my function. The size of a vector will not always be three so I need a function that can create a tuple from three, four and more elements and return it.

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer.

As explained by LogicStuff in a comment, C++ is a statically typed language.

This mean, in your case, that the compiler must known **compile time** the type returned by `create_tuple()`.

Given that the returned type depends from the `size()` of the argument, that is known run-time, the compiler can't choose, compile time, the correct `return` statement so can't choose the correct returned type.

In other words, the critical point is the body of the function

```
if (vec.size() == 2)
    return std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1]);
else if (vec.size() == 3)
    return std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]);
```

En passant: if `vec.size()` is different from `2` or `3` (`1` by example), the compiler don't know what return. But this is a little problem compared to the fact that `std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1])` and `std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2])` gives different and incompatible types.

So the compiler can't choose if the function return a `std::tuple<int, int>` or a `std::tuple<int, int, int>`.

This sort of problem can partially solved starting from C++17, with `if constexpr`

```
if constexpr (vec.size() == 2)
    return std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1]);
else constexpr if (vec.size() == 3)
    return std::make_tuple(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]);
else // ???
```

but also `if constexpr` doesn't works because `if constexpr` require a test that must be decided compile time and with `vec.size()` (where `vec` is a `std::vector`) is impossible.